# Order of arguments and pipe-right operator

Tags: f#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, syntactic-sugar

Is there a way to simplify the following, so I won't need a runWithTimeout function?

```
let runWithTimeout timeout computation =
   Async.RunSynchronously(computation, timeout)

let processOneItem item =  fetchAction item
                           |> runWithTimeout 2000
```

Edit:
Here's why i needed the extra method:

```
let processOneItem item =  fetchAction item
                           |> Async.Catch
                           |> runWithTimeout 2000
                           |> handleExceptions
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. Are you wondering about the cleanest way to write `let processOneItem item = Async.RunSynchronously(fetchAction item, 2000)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you mean something like this:

```
let processOneItem item =
  fetchAction item
  |> fun x -> Async.RunSynchronously(x, 2000)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very keen on using `fun x -> ...` as part of a pipeline.

I think that the pipelining style of writing code is nice when it is supported by the API (e.g. lists), but when the API doesn't fit the style, it is just better to follow the usual "C#-like" style. Of coures, this is just a personal preference, but I'd just write:

```
let processOneItem item =  
  let work = Async.Catch(fetchAction item)
  let result = Async.RunSynchronously(work, 30000)
  handleExceptions result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete sample, for future reference:

```
let processOneItem item =  fetchAction item
                           |> Async.Catch
                           |> fun x -> Async.RunSynchronously(x,30000)
                           |> handleExceptions
```